# Using Lombok to generate "Getters"

Tags: java, getter-setter, lombok

I am taking an introductory course in Object-Oriented Programming.

Our current assignment is to create a version of *"Tower Defense"*, and to help us we are using Junit and Lombok. We have been provided with tons of code to help with the GUI and such, but I don't think that all code is necessary to understand what the problem is, since it is literally the first thing we are supposed to do in the assignment.

```
package edu.chl.hajo.td.model;

import org.junit.Test;

import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;

import static edu.chl.hajo.td.model.TowerDefence.TILE_SIZE;
import static org.junit.Assert.*;


/*
        JUnit testing of model
 */
public class ModelTest {

    @Test
    public void testPath() throws Exception {
         List<String> strPts = Arrays.asList(
                "0,3", "3,3", "3,9", "8,9", "8,4", "12,4",
                "12,12", "3,12", "3,17", "17,17",
                "17,6", "20,6");
        Path p = new Path(0, strPts, TILE_SIZE);


        assertTrue(p.get(0) != null);


        // etc.
    }

    // Add more tests as needed

}
```

So the error message I get is "cannot resolve method 'get(int)'". Here is what I have written in the class 'Path':

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import lombok.Data;
/*
 *   A path for creeps (waves) to follow
 */
public class Path {

    @Getter
    private final int id;

    @Getter
    private final int size;

    @Getter
    private final List<Point2D> points; //= null;  // TODO




    // TODO

    public Path(int id, List list, int size) {
        this.id = id;
        this.points = list;
        this.size = size;
    }

}
```

But if I understand "Getters" correctly, the @Getter only creates methods like getId, getSize, and getPoints. What really is the test trying to do with get(0)? I feel like it would make sense if the thing we wanted to get something from was a list, but here we are trying to get something from a Path.

I hope some of this makes sense to someone.

Comment: regardless of lombok, it seems you are meant to write `get()` method that (perhaps) gets a point from the list

Comment: `p.getPoints().get(0)` would make a lot more sense. (Note also that there's an `assertNotNull` method; `assertTrue` is a last-resort when there isn't a more specific matcher available.)

Answer (score 1):

I think you are supposed to implement the `Path` class such that when the constructor is called as in the test the Path is created with a list of `Point2D` for each coordinate. And `get(int i)` is a method you have to implement to return that point from the path.

Lombok implements simple getters (like `getId()`), but not necessarily a more complex `get(int i)` method that returns a specific point from the path.

Comment: Yes I think this is the case, our instructor put so much emphasis on Lombok so I figured it was magic I guess.